# Start a redis server during jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, jestjs

I am trying to write tests for a service that uses `ioredis` to connect to an elasticache server in AWS. I want to be able to isolate tests from the integration points and want to be able to connect to a redis server locally during the jest tests.

I am able to run setup/teardown of local infrastructure components via `jest. One of the necessary components is redis.

I don't see any tools to be able to start an in-memory server of redis for your application to then use and connect to via localhost:port.

The only thing I found is `https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-server` which is 2 years old. Is this still the recommended tool for this type of job?

I can also try to start a docker container of redis during jest, but don't see any tools to be able to run the docker container from within jest.

Has anyone been able to solve this problem? The `ioredis-mock` is not really what I'm looking for as it seems to replace the entire `ioredis` suite instead of just allowing the 'real' `ioredis` to connect to a redis implementation over tcp (whether it be the real thing or a mock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always drop to the command line, and do what you need there. In the jest setup just run redis as you normally would via the command line, and in teardown do the same.
[Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: True, but then how can I ensure redis is installed on the machine that this is running on? Is there a way to install it as a dependency via yarn/npm?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. 
But, ask yourself what would you do if you need postgress or mysql databases? How would you solve it then?
If you are working with multiple developers, then you need to assure that they all have the same environments as close as possible. You could use docker and docker compose to create a full environment for your application. Put those docker compose files in your repository, so everyone just needs to run docker-compose and they will have redis database available.

Comment: I hear you, but we will be running this test as part of CI and need to make sure every step is repeatable and automated. So as part of that I need to ensure that the dockerfile that's running the test has all deps it needs to run the test, including redis. But also that developers have what they need if running the test from the command line. Can I run docker-compose from CI during multi stage dockerfile build (that's currently how test is run) thx for you help...

Comment: I don't think you can run docker-compose on CI (at least on circleCI) however you can run multiple containers. So if you have two containers (nodejs , redis) then in your jest tests, you just need to pass in the connection information for redis. No need to start redis yourself. Take a look at [CircleCI PostgreSQL testing example](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/databases/#postgresql-database-testing-example)

Comment: So using `child_process` worked for the tests when just running from my machine, but when I try to have them run during the docker build process, it can't find docker. I'm going to open up a new question for that specific problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136981/docker-build-cant-find-docker-to-run-tests

Answer (score 1):

There is a great project on GitHub, that helps you starting a in-memory redis server for testing (without a password) in your pipeline:
https://github.com/mhassan1/redis-memory-server.

If you use and like the project, leave the author a star and contribute if you can.

If you are using something like vitest or jest, your code could look similar to this:

```
import { Redis } from 'ioredis';
import { RedisMemoryServer } from 'redis-memory-server';

const redisServer = new RedisMemoryServer();

describe("redis tests", () => {
  const redisPort = await redisServer.getHost();
  const redisHost = await redisServer.getPort();

  // Tests
  it("connects", async () => {
  // Test code e.g. ioredis
    new Redis({
      port: redisPort,
      host: redisHost ,
    });
  }
  afterAll(async () => {
    await redisServer.stop();
  })
}
```