# Docker build can't find docker to run tests

Tags: docker, jestjs

I have a NodeJS application that is using `ioredis` to connect to redis and publish data and other redisy things.

I am trying to write a component test against redis and was able to create a setup/teardown script via jest that runs redis via docker on a random port and tears it down when the tests are done via `docker run -d -p 6379 --rm redis` and `docker stop {containerId}`.

This works great locally, but we have the tests running in a multi-stage build in our Dockerfile: 
`RUN yarn test`

which I try to build via `docker build .` it goes great until it gets to the tests and then complains with the following error - `/bin/sh: docker: not found`

Hence, Docker is unavailable to the docker-build process to run the tests?

Is there a way to run docker-build to give it the ability to spin up sibling processes during the process?

Answer (score 1):

This smells to me like a "docker-in-docker" situation.

You can't spin up siblings, but you can spawn a container within a container, by doing some tricks: (you might need to do some googling to get it right)

- install the docker binaries in the "host container"
- mount the docker socket from the actual host inside the "host" container, like so `docker run  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...`

But you won't be able to do it in the build step, so it won't be easy for your case.

I suggest you prepare a dedicated build container capable of running nested containers, which would basically emulate your local env and use that in your CI. Still, you might need to refactor your process a bit make it work.

Good luck :)

Comment: Right now I'm just running `docker build` from my local machine, I haven't pushed to a CI yet. I was trying to avoid `docker-in-docker` specifically, since I read that's bad practice.

Comment: well, good or bad, if you need to run a docker container during a docker build, I don't know of another easier way. It's not necessarily bad, it's bad if you have a huge process and multiple layers of containers, that's when I imagine things would get hairy. If you go for it, document the strategy coz that's important :)

Comment: I decided to install redis in the container via `RUN apk add --no-cache redis` which allows me to run redis-server and redis-cli for the tests. Since I use multi-stage docker file, it only gets installed for the test stage and it won't be present in the final docker container.

Comment: I like the idea of a dedicated build container that emulates the local env, though very nice. I might pursue that on the side :)

Answer (score 0):

In my practice, tests shouldn't be concerned with initializing the database, they should only be concerned about how to connect to the database, so you just pass your db connection data via environment variables.

The way you are doing it it won't scale, imagine that you need a lot more services for your application, it will be difficult and not practical to start them via tests.

When you are developing locally, it's your responsibility to have the services running before doing the tests.

You can have docker compose scripts in your repository that create and start all the services you need when you start developing.

And when you are using CI in the cloud, you would still use docker containers and run tests in them( node container with your tests, redis container, mysql container, etc...) and again just pass the appropriate connection data via environment variables.

Comment: If that's the case, why did jest provide setup/teardown extensions to be able to start and stop necessary infrastructure of your application to run tests against? I'd say if your application is starting to connect to too many services that it's becoming increasingly difficult to test it, then your application might be getting too big and that becomes an architectural question. In my experience, making devs have to rely on bootstrapping too much external config to run tests, just means they won't run them lol

Comment: setup/teardown is used for doing one-time setups, or tasks that are complicated or expensive to do per test file.
It's not optimal to start containers every time you run tests. If you are doing integration testing you should have a database already running, and just connect to it, everything else just complicates things unnecessarily.

Comment: In jest's config documentation they show an example of starting and stopping mongodb. These aren't integration tests, they're component tests. I was trying to start a redis double, but that doesn't exist in the javascript ecosystem apparently. Integration tests will be performed in the real environment with the environment provided redis.